# What is $\mathcal{L}_M$?

Tags: general-relativity, terminology, action, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, matter

Usually we derive the Einstein field equation in vacuum starting from [E-H action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action)
$$S= \int{\sqrt{-g}d^4x(\frac{c^4}{16\pi G})R}.$$

But in case we wanted to get

$$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu},$$
a.k.a, in the presence of matter, then the action is always presented as 
$$S= \int\sqrt{-g}d^4x\left(\frac{c^4}{16\pi G} R+\mathcal{L}_{M}\right).$$
What does $\mathcal{L}_M$ stand for here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are to have $T^{\mu\nu}$ in the r.h.s. of Einsteins equation, then you must have some source for that $T^{\mu\nu}$. It could be dust, EM radiation, or any other source of energy. $\mathcal L_M$ is the lagrangian that is expected to describe these sources of energy. For example, the lagrangian for electromagnetism is
$$
\mathcal L_M=(\nabla_{[\mu}A_{\nu]})^2
$$

On the other hand, you can model dust by $\mathcal L_M= \sqrt{p^2}$ for example. Any lagrangian that is supposed to model any other field apart from gravity is included in $\mathcal L_M$.

This lagrangian is related to $T^{\mu\nu}$ through
$$
T^{\mu\nu}=-2\frac{\delta \mathcal L_M}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}
$$
(google Hilbert stress–energy tensor)

Answer (score 3):

This is the Lagrangian (lagrangian density, to be exact) of all matter fields, all the terms that are not purely gravitational. It usually include scalar fields, spinor fields, EM fields, point masses, all those kinds of things.